# API for Microsoft Teams Rooms

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any documentation for [Microsoft Teams Rooms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/microsoft-teams-rooms)? We need to add our custom plugin to the Microsoft Teams Rooms but we are unable to find any info about it. We only know, it is possible since other companies like Extron have their own plugins.

Comment: Could you please refer below doc for Microsoft Teams Rooms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/rooms/

Comment: Could you please share more specifics of what kind of documentation you are looking for?

Comment: Hello @Nivedipa-MSFT, I am looking for documentation, how can I include my own plugin directly to Microsoft Teams Rooms application. Something like Room controls app from OEMs developers.

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft Teams Room, there's no support for customers to add extensions to the room systems today, it's only limited to device OEMs.